# R sum over rows - Data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have the following `data.frame`,

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
                 d0=c(1,1,0,1,1,0),
                 d1=c(0,0,0,0,1,1),
                 d2=c(0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 d3=c(1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 d4=c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 d5=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))

  id d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
1  a  1  0  0  1  1  1
2  b  1  0  0  1  0  1
3  c  0  0  1  0  1  1
4  d  1  0  1  1  0  1
5  e  1  1  1  1  0  1
6  f  0  1  1  1  1  1
```

How can I count the max number of zeros between two pairs of 1?
For example

```
1 0 1 --> 1
1 0 0 1 --> 2
0 1 --> 0
1 0 1 0 1 --> 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 --> 2
```

So the final output would be:

```
  id d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 final
  a  1  0  0  1  1  1     2
  b  1  0  0  1  0  1     2
  c  0  0  1  0  1  1     1
  d  1  0  1  1  0  1     1
  e  1  1  1  1  0  1     1
  f  0  1  1  1  1  1     0
```

Can someone help with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created an auxiliary function to find the maximum number of zeros between 2 ones.

```
count_zeros <- function(vec){
  pos_ones <- which(vec == 1)
  count_zero <-NULL
  for(i in 1:(length(pos_ones)-1)){
    count_zero <- c(count_zero,length(which(vec[pos_ones[i]:pos_ones[i+1]] == 0)))
  }
  return(max(count_zero))
}
```

it just loops between the number of ones found in a vector `vec`, it counts the number of zeros in the vector and returns the maximum number. With this it is just easy to loop the whole data frame. This is an approach with `sapply`

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) count_zeros(df[x,-1]))
```

the result is:

```
[1] 2 2 1 1 1 0
```

that is what you expect

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using `apply` and `rle` after converting your data.frame to a matrix (excluding the ID).

```
# convert data to matrix
myMat <- data.matrix(df[-1])
```

Now, get the counts. The first and last values are set to 0, since the goal is to get counts of 0s between 1s.

```
# get the counts
apply(myMat, 1,
      function(x) {
        # get run lengths of 0s and 1s
        tmp <- rle(x)
        # set first and last values to 0
        tmp$lengths[c(1, length(tmp$lengths))] <- 0
        # return maximum count of 0s
        max(tmp$lengths[tmp$values==0])
})
```

This returns

```
[1] 2 2 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can view our groups of zeros as by `cumsums` on rows, except that when `cumsum` is `0` the group is not valid as it didn't start with `1`.

We use `tapply` to count zero values (i.e. sum `FALSE`) by group and keep the max:

```
apply(df[-1],1,function(row) max(tapply(!row,replace(x <- cumsum(row),!x,NA),sum)))
# [1] 2 2 1 1 1 0
```

Here's a more detailed version :

```
cs <- apply(df[-1],1,cumsum)
cs[cs==0] <- NA
sapply(seq(nrow(df)),function(i) max(tapply(!df[i,-1],cs[,i],sum)))
```